# How to build GTK+ application with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: windows, gtk3, visual-studio-2019

I installed GTK+ 3.0 as described on https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php
I cloned the git and typed `vcpkg install gtk:x64-windows`
Everything build well.
I then opened Visual Studio 2019 and tried to create a console application using C++. I changed the project so it compiles in C instead of C++. However, when I type `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` it doesn't show on auto complete. I'm not sure where to go from here. Can someone give me any pointers? I want to build a statically linked gtk-3.0 application using visual studio 2019. I already designed the interface on Glade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have ran the command "vcpkg integrate install" in your vcpkg directory, all you need to do is change the configuration in visual studio to x64 as shown in the screenshot.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqXB9.jpg)