# what .lib files is needed for gtk in visual studio in c?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gtk

I installed gtk to my computer and I need to add it visual studio 2019 c project. Does anyone knows what .lib I need to add to the linker input settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build GTK+ application with Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57717155/how-to-build-gtk-application-with-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: No. I managed to add gtk to vs and include it with auto complete but when I hit build there are some linking errors. But thanks anyway